# Bootstrap 4 External content toggler outline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, bootstrap-4

**Hi!**
I added a new External content navigation from v4 Bootstrap components and I changed .navbar-toggler-icon for image. When I click on that icon/img there is a blue outline that I hate and I want it to be gone but I have totaly 0 idea how to do it.

```
x:hover,
x:active,
x:focus {
 outline: none;
 border: 0px;
}
```

doesn't work at all.

Feel free to take a look at the code at [Website](http://www.km-studio.hol.es)

Answer (score 0):

If you put `outline:none` on the button itself then the blue will go away.  Something like:

```
.navbar-toggler:focus {
    outline:none;
}
```

Here is a codepen with it working.  Sorry I copied all your html so the images are all broken:
http://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/bgpORY

Comment: @KacperMateuszMurzyn you are absolutely right.  Sorry about that.  It was working in my inspector but I forgot to add the `:focus`.  Answer updated now.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem!  If this helped solved your issue you can mark it as correct :) Thanks!